# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client

Tags: plugins, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am stuck on this exception already for two days.
I am using MS CRM 2011, and got this exception when I try to register CRM custom worklow activity assembly 
      1. through pluginregistrator tool,
      2.  or when I deploy the plugin though package project in Visual Studio and after it run the the workflow, and it stops with waiting  status, in the details page giving this expcetion. Here is the detailed exception:

> Workflow paused due to error: Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9688.1154, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at ArmenianSoftware.Crm.Spayka.ArmsoftIntegration.Workflows.CreateWorksByPlan.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I am registering assembly on the file system, I have loaded all needed assemblies in the folder %system root%\C$\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\assembly. This workflow worked some time, but after I don't know what, next time I deployed the assembly, I got this exception when executing the workflow. This is already third time I am coming across this problem, and spoiling several hours trying to do different things (IIS reset, Async Service restarts, reloading all the assemblies again and redeploying), and after several hours, in a mysterious way, the workflow starts to work. After this works some time, and after some redeployment crashes again. And I can't determine after exactly what steps I solve the problem, and so I spend always several hours on finding out the exception source but to no purpose.
 I have looked through some threads in the web but none of them was my case (here are they [thread1](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdeployment/thread/f1cea2b4-0b19-45bc-afe4-5ef7e7b609dd) , [thread2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2011/04/21/crm-service-exception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel-version-3-5-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-31bf3856ad364e35-or-one-of-its-dependencies.aspx) , [thread3](http://stefanscheller.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-xrm-client-at-plugin-registration/))
Have anybody come across this problem? What is the reason of this exception??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have already found the problem, but I can't answer my question during 8 hours (due to low rating), I'll write detailed description in tomorrow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the problem in my case!

First thing I have noticed was that the in the Exception the required version of the Microsoft.Xrm.Client assembly was 5.0.9688.1154, but in my project I have the reference to the assembly of version 5.0.9689.1985.

[image]

And the next thing was the open ildasm tool, and look what referenced  does it have, I opened my custom workflow assembly and I've found that I have two references to Microsoft.Xrm.Client,
first of version 5.0.9688.1154, and the second: 5.0.9689.1985
[image]

And a question arose "If I have referenced a assembly the version of wich is 5.0.9689.1985, why there is another version of this assembly? ". And the answer was, definitely, that I had another referenced assembly, which referenced Microsoft.Xrm.Client assembly with version 5.0.9688.1154. I have looked through the assemblies I have reference to in my project. And GOTCHA! In my project I have updated the SDK asseblies to a newer version, but I also had the generated CRM organization Proxy classes assembly, which references Microsoft.Xrm.Client, and I haven't updated this reference to a newer version of CRM SDK. So my custom workflow assembly also needed this version. I changed the references of Proxy dll to newer version, and everything went OK!
If you are reading this post, and you don't have proxy assembly, check your other assemblies, if they all reference the same version of the CRM SDK, if not correct them!

Regards

Gagik Kyurkchyan